# Trying to get an Hbox to be in front of a parent Pane

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I've just been trying to put a blue box inside of a black box, to put it simply.

I have a class called DialoguePane, which extends Javafx Pane. It also has a field, an HBox that's supposed to hold buttons called actionButtonHBox, which I want to put inside of the DialoguePane.

Below is a picture of the window. The box with the label "select an action" is the DialoguePane object. Right now I'm as far as I have the two boxes inside one another. However, when I try to call the .setBackground method or use css styling to try to style the background of the Hbox, nothing changes, the background does not change. I also use toFront(), but nothing changes. I'm glad I'm at least at the point of having the boxes properly inside of one another, but I just want to change the background color of this region for formatting and design purposes.

[image: picture of javafx window]

Here's relevant parts of the Dialogue Pane's constructor

```
public class DialoguePane extends Pane {
     private HBox actionButtonHbox;
     public DialoguePane(String string) {
         super();
         this.resizeRelocate(480, 200, 450, 140); //Makes the DialoguePane's whole region have a width of 450, height of 140, at position x-cor 480px and y-cor 200px
         this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .95)");
         //this.setDisplayableText(string);
         this.makeActionButtonHbox();
     }
     public void makeActionButtonHbox() {
         actionButtonHbox = new HBox();
         System.out.println("Before: " + actionButtonHbox.backgroundProperty());
         actionButtonHbox.resizeRelocate(0, 100, 400, 40); //Sets it at this position inside of the DialoguePane, a box with 400 width and 40 height. It's pretty thin.
         actionButtonHbox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
         actionButtonHbox.toFront();
         System.out.println("After " + actionButtonHbox.backgroundProperty());
         this.getChildren().add(actionButtonHbox);
}
```

There's other code that's responsible for putting a TextArea above the hbox (which is what says "Select an Action below" in the Pane, which happens in the setDisplayableText method).

So what could I do to make the background of this pane visible?

Comment: The print statements, "before" and "after" are there to show if the backgroundProperty of the hbox ever gets initialized... According to the print messages, _it does._

Comment: **Interesting** Changing DialoguePane from extending a Pane object to extending a BorderPane object made the actionButtonHbox's background display.

Comment: You don't have any `Nodes` in your `HBox`, so it appears the `HBox` size is 0. Try adding this `actionButtonHbox.setMinSize(100, 100);`

Comment: @SedrickJefferson that's the answer it seems.